# What is the name of this plant?

Tags: food-identification

I buy things off the street and in markets with no labels. What is this so I can google it? [image]

Comment: In my local store it's called "linh tinh", which is Vietnamese for "miscellaneous".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like watercress to me and Max.